# XPath not working in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following XPath that I am trying to extract data from:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/ul[2]/li/div
```

I am trying to simply test this through Scrapy Shell, so I do the following:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.rentler.com/listing/520583"
```

and then:

```
hxs.select('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/ul[2]/li/div').extract()
```

But this returns `[]`.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

The whole reason that I want to do this is because I need to breakup these 5 items into individual variables, not one array (which I currently have working):

```
<ul class="basic-stats">
<li>
<div class="count">4</div>
<div class="label">Bed</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="count">2</div>
<div class="label">Bath</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="count">1977</div>
<div class="label">Year</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="count">1960</div>
<div class="label">SqFt</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="count">0</div>
<div class="label">Acres</div>
</li>
```

Comment: do any of those intermediary elements have a `class` or an `id` you can reference,  that would reduce the complexity of your xpath expression

Comment: @dm03514 Yes, but why would the full path not work?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. To access the individual items above, you simply add li[1],li[2], etc.